# .htaccess remap redirect on different subdomain

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, apache2

I am trying to make my AngularJS application discoverable by social networks, and I've came across the following github page:

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angular-social-demo

However I got stuck at the `.htaccess` step. The following code is being used to redirect (using remapping) the facebook/twitter/google bots to a different URL (on the same domain):

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

# allow social media crawlers to work by redirecting them to a server-rendered static version on the page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule album/(\d*)$ http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/experiments/angular-social-demo/server/static-page.php?id=$1 [P]

</ifModule>
```

What I am trying to do, is very similar to what he did, however, my API is a subdomain.

Is `.htaccess` redirect remapping possible when a different subdomain is used?

Example:

`http://www.example.com/test/123` remap to `http://api.example.com/title/test/123` and keep browser URL as `http://www.example.com/test/123`.

Comment: You don't actually say what the problem is? Are you getting an error when you try this method? The directives given as an example are already intended to work across hosts (although that is not actually necessary if "on same domain" - as in that example!?), providing mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are already installed/enabled on your server.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need http://www.example.com/test/123 remap to http://api.example.com/title/test/123 without redirect in general i.e. without need for the special `HTTP_USER_AGENT` condition:

### Content on external server

If you need to keep the browser URL's domain part as is and the content is on different server, it's not internal [Redirecting or Remapping](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) anymore and you'd have to use [Reverse Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) instead.

While the `[P]` flag used in your example causes the request to be handled via a proxy request by [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html), it is not recommended:

> Performance warning
>
> Using this flag triggers the use of mod_proxy, without handling of
>   persistent connections. This means the performance of your proxy will
>   be better if you set it up with `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassMatch`. This is
>   because this flag triggers the use of the default worker, which does
>   not handle connection pooling. Avoid using this flag and prefer those
>   directives, whenever you can.

The [`ProxyPass` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) that *Maps remote servers into the local server URL-space* is only available in the contexts *server config*, *virtual host* and *directory*, but **not available in `.htaccess` context**.

If you don't have access to the server configuration, you can only do this with `RewriteRule` as it is allowed in `.htaccess` context. That's exactly as in the example of your question.

If you can access the `<VirtualHost>` configuration (or ask for a modification), you could add there:

```
<Location "/test/">
    ProxyPass "http://api.example.com/title/test/"
</Location>
```

### Content on the same server

If the content is physically on the same server but on a different `<VirtualHost>`, the simplest way is not to use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) at all, but [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html). The `Alias` directive allows documents to be stored in the local filesystem other than under the `DocumentRoot`.

```
Alias "/test" "/path/to/api/title/test"
```

---

### If you only need to remap in the case of special user-agents

In this case with AngularJS application it seems that you only want to remap the url when it is visited by social media crawlers. In this case you really need to use `RewriteCond` and with the following `RewriteRule`s you can use the condition from your question.

First **make sure you have [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) installed**, otherwise you won't be able to use `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` at all.

If the content is on **external server** and you can't avoid using `[P]`:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://api.example.com/title/test/$1 [P]
```

If you are in the `.htaccess` context, you shouldn't match `^test/(.*)$` but the current directory:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://api.example.com/title/test/$1 [P]
```

If the content is on **different path on the same server**, you can use file-system path for substitution, but this cannot be done in `.htaccess`:

> Substitutions are only treated as a file-system path when the rule is
>   configured in server (virtualhost) context and the first component of
>   the path in the substitution exists in the file-system.

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /path/to/api/title/test/$1
```

**I didn't use `\d*`** from your example: the [metacharacter](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php) `\d` limits the match only to digit characters.

Comment: Can I add conditions as in htaccess provided above?

Comment: "If you don't have access to the server configuration, you can only do this as a redirect in `.htaccess`" - The (`.htaccess`) mod_rewrite directives given as an example in the question already use mod_proxy to proxy the request (that's what the `P` flag is for). (Although, if this was "on the same domain", then that would have been unnecessary - it would have been preferable to simply _internally rewrite_ the request in that case.)

Comment: Thanks, @w3dk. I missed the `[P]` flag in the end of line! As it still should be avoided, I tried to explain conditions when it can or cannot be avoided. I also noticed that the `\d*` metacharacter might have caused extra limitation that isn't needed in this case.